# fullcalendar: allDay events not listed in the agendaWeek

Tags: fullcalendar

I've problems with the allDay option in the fullcalendar (v2.2.3). When I use the view "month", I can see all my allDay events. But when I switch to the agendaWeek view, they are missing.

My calendar week begins on Tuesday (firstDay: 2). Sunday and Monday are hidden (hiddenDays: [0, 1]). When an event starts at Tuesday and allDay is set to true, the event is missing on the agendaWeek view.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar(
header:
  left: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
  center: 'title'
  right: "today prev,next"

minTime: '07:00:00'
maxTime: '20:30:00'
defaultView: "agendaWeek"

timezone: 'Bern'
lang: 'de'

allDaySlot: true
firstDay: 3
hiddenDays: [0, 1]
weekNumbers: true
editable: false
slotDuration: '00:30:00'
snapDuration: '00:15:00'
slotEventOverlap: true
axisFormat: 'HH:mm'

selectable: true
selectHelper: true

events: (start, end, timezone, callback) ->
  $.ajax
    url: $('#calendar').data('url')
    dataType: "json"
    type: 'GET'

    success: (data) ->
      events = []
      $.each data, (index, element) ->
        events.push
          id: element.id
          title: element.title
          start: element.start
          end: element.end
          color: '#' + element.color
          allDay: element.allDay

      callback events
```

And my json file looks like:

```
[{"id":100,"start":"2014-12-16T00:00:00.000+01:00","end":"2014-12-17T23:59:59.999+01:00","title":"Here is a title","color":"8884a2","allDay":true},{"id":101,"start":"2014-12-17T00:00:00.000+01:00","end":"2014-12-18T23:59:59.999+01:00","title":"Here is a title","color":"8884a2","allDay":true}]
```

All other events (not allDay events) are correctly listed in the calendar.